# Matching multiple words and print the string

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match     abc (VIA) and display the entire line

INPUT:

```
abc (VIA)                    -0.090

total : abc                   0.021

abc (sometext) (VIA)         -0.080

abc (without text)  (VIA)   -0.059
```

OUTPUT:

```
abc (VIA)                    -0.090
```

I am using code like this:

```
    if ($line =~ /abc (VIA) (\-\d+\.\d+) / )

         {

          print OUT " $line \n"   ;

          }
```

Comment: Do you want to print out the entire line or only part of it? In your question above, you say the entire line, but in your comment below, you say you only want to print out the value after (VIA). Which is it?

Comment: HI, first I tried to print the entire line. once it is done, I was trying to print only the value. So I added it up in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape parentheses and match only the string you want to match i.e.:

```
$line =~ /abc \(VIA\)/
```

no need to match numbers after this as per your question.

Comment: I am trying to print only the value in it. Should I use split function to split the line and print it?

Comment: If you want just the value, you really don't need to mess with the rest: `(-?\d+\.\d+)`

Comment: HI Adam, Thank you. I want to print the value in the strings which I matched. Like I wanna print only  -0.090 instead of the other values.

Comment: You can use: `$line =~ /abc \(VIA\) +(.+)/` and print `$1`

Answer (score 1):

Each of the match is saved in default variables.

Match as:

```
$line =~ /(abc)(\s)(\(VIA\))/;

$1 will have first match i.e., abc
$2 will have second match i.e., space character
$3 will have third match i.e., (VIA) and so on.
```

Just use the variables.They are filled by default.